# XAML is calling get with a prior binding

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

XAML is calling set on a prior binding with the value of the new binding

Call stack

```
Gabe2a.exe!Gabe2a.GabeLib.SearchItem.ParenRight1.set(bool value) Line 24333 C#
[External Code] 
Gabe2a.exe!Gabe2a.PageSearch.NotifyPropertyChanged(string info) Line 34 C#
```

searchItemCur is correct

```
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PageSearch NotifyPropertyChanged " + info);
        if ( info == "SearchItemCur"  && searchItemCur != null)
            Debug.WriteLine("   searchItemCur " + searchItemCur.FieldDef.DispName);
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Below is called on the wrong Object
The identified FieldDef.DispName is wrong
It is called on the old binding with the new value

```
public Boolean ParenRight3
{
    get { return parenRight3; }
    set
    {
        if (parenRight3 == value) return;
        Debug.WriteLine("ParenRight3 " + value.ToString() + " " + FieldDef.DispName);
        if (value && (AndOr == enumAndOr.Except || AndOr == enumAndOr.NotYetDefined)) return;
        parenRight3 = value;
```

I have traced it down
It breaks at [External Code] which I am pretty sure is XAML
That line is calling the old binding with a value of the new binding
Assign the value of the new binding to the binding results in an incorrect value
If the old and the new both have the same value then there is no call to get at all

```
Gabe2a.exe!Gabe2a.GabeLib.SearchItem.ParenRight1.set(bool value) Line 24333 C#
[External Code] 
Gabe2a.exe!Gabe2a.PageSearch.NotifyPropertyChanged(string info) Line 34 C#
```

This is the binding

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButton03}" FontSize="14" Content=")"
            IsChecked="{Binding  ElementName=_this, Path=SearchItemCur.ParenRight1}"/>
```

There is a separate DataContext

Comment: Radio buttons and bindings can interact in some funny ways, due to the fact that changed IsChecked on a radio button also implicitly changes it on other radio buttons in the same group.  When this change happens as a result of a binding changing, you can wind up in situations where IsChecked is changed due to a binding, which changes IsChecked on another radio button, which then modifies the 'old' object, since the binding change hadn't fully propagated yet.

Comment: @DanBryant What is strange is the other RadioButton are working.  And it is always sending the value of the new binding even if the value is true.  But something to ponder.

Comment: @DanBryant Nice catch.  I changed them to CheckBoxes and the problem seems to have gone away.  Man I fought this for 4 hours.

Comment: @DanBryant If you will post that with a bit of explanation I would be happy to accept it.  I put each in a separate group and problem went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, radio buttons and bindings interact in some funny ways, due to the automatic setting of IsChecked on other radio buttons as a result of the interactions within a group.  I ran into this when dealing with radio buttons as part of a Data Template.  When you change the DataContext, it will reuse the visual tree created for the template, but then propagate the changed DataContext to all of the radio buttons inside.  This causes the same result you observed with a nested path in the binding.

Here is a Check Box style that has been retemplated to look like a Radio Button.  This is missing a few style resources, but you can hack it a bit to work with whatever styles your app uses.  Note the 'IsHitTestVisible' hack; that's used to prevent the user from 'unchecking' a check box that's supposed to act like a radio button.

```
<Style x:Key="RadioCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource RadioButtonFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxBg}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource NuclearRadioCheckBox}" />
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource InvBool}}"/>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="NuclearRadioCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <Grid Width="13" Height="13">
                <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse_Border" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="InnerBorder" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource CheckBoxInnerBorderBrush}" Margin="2" />
                <Ellipse Margin="3" x:Name="CheckMark" Stroke="#FFAA5B0B">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFAF" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFE9E45" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFE38A" Offset="0.325" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFBA61" Offset="0.663" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
            </Grid>
        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
        <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </BulletDecorator>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="CheckMark" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}" TargetName="Ellipse_Border" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxInnerBorderHoverBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Ellipse_Border" Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxHoverBorderBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource PressedBrush}" TargetName="Ellipse_Border" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}" TargetName="Ellipse_Border" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Ellipse_Border" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#40000000" TargetName="Ellipse_Border" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```